# Linux Icon Naming Conventions

Tags: linux, files, filenames, icons, conventions

Is there a naming convention in Linux when it comes to application icon filenames? What I'm referring to is the practice of including the icon size in the filename if the application uses multiple icon files (PNGs, for example) for different views (desktop, lists, menus, etc.).

OS X has the `icon_16x16`, `icon_32x32`, etc. convention, so I'm wondering if there's a similar practice in Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but Linux separates different sizes of icons into different directories instead of giving them different names.  You'll want to read the [Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html), which explains the directory layout, and the [Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html), which explains how the filenames should be chosen.

To summarize, Linux application icons would be something like:

```
/usr/share/icons/<theme-name>/<icon-size>/apps/<program-name>.png
```